# Wildcard of Number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, wildcard

How to match numbers in SQL Server 'LIKE'.

```
SpaceName
------------ 
| New_Space_1
| .
| .
| New_Space_8 
| New_Space_9
| New_Space_10
| New_Space_11
| New_Space_SomeString
| New_Space_SomeString1
```

Above is  my table contents.
I want to get only records ending with Numeric chars, ie I want the records from `New_Space_1` to `New_Space_11`.

Don't want `New_Space_SomeString` and `New_Space_SomeString1`

I have some query like this.

```
SELECT SpaceName FROM SpaceTable
    WHERE SpaceName LIKE 'New_Space_%'
```

But this returns all records.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solution from @SteveKass works perfect.

```
SELECT SpaceName FROM SpaceTable WHERE SpaceName LIKE 'New[_]Space[_]%' AND SpaceName NOT LIKE 'New[_]Space[_]%[^0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 23):

what about

```
SELECT SpaceName FROM SpaceTable
    WHERE SpaceName LIKE 'New[_]Space[_][0-9]%'
```

The reason I put underscore in brackets is because in a regular expression _ means Any single character. Read up on like here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: One problem.. this `New_Space_8-56` is also returned by the Query

Comment: How about this: SELECT SpaceName FROM SpaceTable
WHERE SpaceName LIKE 'New[\_]Space[\_]%'
AND SpaceName NOT LIKE 'New[\_]Space[\_]%[^0-9]%'